# Centering images in a Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html

As the title states I am having trouble getting images to center in my bootstrap carousel. The 4 images are 640x480 and keep aligning to the left of the carousel. I have uploaded my code to codepen and if anyone can help me with this problem, it'd be greatly appreciated. I have had a look at some solutions on stackoverflow but I haven't been able to fix the problem.

`http://codepen.io/omfggrenade/pen/wWOKER`

```
<body>
<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">The Big Cats</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
        </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `class="center-block"` on `img`

Comment: I tried adding class="center-block" to my code and it doesn't look like it affects anything. I'm starting to think this code is cursed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Adam Azad's comment, there's working example:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<div class="container">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
     <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="item active">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://placehold.it/640x480?text=Slide+1">
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://placehold.it/640x480?text=Slide+2">
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://placehold.it/640x480?text=Slide+3">
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img class="center-block" src="http://placehold.it/640x480?text=Slide+4">
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
 </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/bra1N/pen/QEoyLL

Comment: Note that this will merely center the image horizontally.

Comment: I don't know if you changed anything other than class="center-block", but the code works. When I added the code snippet, it refused to work. After I copied and pasted your example, it works! Thank you for your contribution!